# Granting service accounts access to AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, basic-authentication

I'm wondering what is the correct way to grant service accounts access to AzureDevOps. Ex: access to source code, API's, etc.

Since "Basic Authentication" was deactivated, I've been using personal access tokens but it seems awkward to login using a service account, generating the PAT, and so on. Also, since they are limited in time, we have to ensure renewal schedules/reminders for each connexions.

I am on the wrong track? Is there a more "natural" way to do it? Is SSH more adapted for this?

I've found this guide which helps but I can't find how (for example) granting a third-party application access to a project's repository.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops

PS: Service Connections and Service Hooks are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for probably is **OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow** for Azure DevOps. Unfortunately **Client Credentials Flow** is not yet supported on Azure DevOps. See this thread [Client Credentials Flow for Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875738/client-credentials-flow-for-azure-devops).

But, You can check out **OAuth 2.0 auth code flow**,which is now supported on Azure Devops. Please check out this detailed tutorial [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops). This is [an example](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample) to implement OAuth 2.0 auth code flow.

There are also Codes samples provided in above [web link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) you mentioned in the question. You can checkout these samples to learn their authentication mechanism, and choose one that suits you most.