# Use Azure AD Managed Identity/Service Principal user in ADO to use ADO API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I was following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops to create a custom branch policy. The gist of the article is: when an ADO PR is created or updated, the following happens:

- ADO invokes an Azure Functions webhook
- Azure Functions execute some custom branch policy logic (e.g. adds custom status to the PR).

Azure functions use [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) to authenticate with ADO to post a custom status. Two things I don't like about this approach:

- PAT's max life span is 2 years. After 2 years you need to update your PAT token - easy to forget, extra effort to automate.
- PAT is issued by a user. I'd like to have a separate "system" user for the custom branch policy. I don't want to reuse an "alive" user (people tend to quit) nor I want to create a "fake" live user for this purpose (company's security policies implications).

So, I wonder if there is a way to use Azure Functions Managed Identity/Service Principal directly in ADO: give ADO permissions to the managed identity and use Azure AD token to authenticate user in ADO API.

I know that you can set up your ADO organization to user Azure AD users. This is how my organization is set up currently:
[image]
All "alive" users are shown but I don't see any Managed Identities/Service Principals. It looks like only users are synchronized with ADO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Azure AD Managed Identity/Service Principal user which uses Client credentials flow are not supported to authenticate to ADO.

You can see that there is no related Authenticate method which you want in [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#authenticate).

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875738/client-credentials-flow-for-azure-devops?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

[Using Managed Identity is possible now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops)

With python, you can do something like this:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.connection import Connection

credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
ADO_APP_CLIENT_ID = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
accessToken = credentials.get_token(ADO_APP_CLIENT_ID)
auth = BasicAuthentication("", accessToken.token)
azure_devops_connection = Connection(base_url="<ado org url>", creds=auth)
... do whatever you want
azure_devops_client = azure_devops_connection.clients.get_git_client()
```

using DefaultAzureCredential you can connect using managed identity, service principle, az cli and more see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python) for available env var configuration.